# Image no margin inside a div

Tags: html, css

In the picture below I have an image inside a yellow div. I don't like the left, right and top margins, but I want to keep the bottom margin so that I can add text later, so how do I get rid of those margins? I still want to keep rounded corners at the top.

http://s16.postimg.org/i1r2kfy5v/Screen_Shot_2015_07_31_at_11_35_27_PM.png

The code is simple as you see:

```
<div>
  <div>
    <a ...><img ...></a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

========== update =============

To be more specific, I just created a jsfiddle test:

http://jsfiddle.net/wpp3ejer/5/

so basically I wanted the yellow block to be fixed width, but I don't want left/right/top paddings. When there is no top margin, I can't make the top corners rounded, and I also can't get rid off the right margin.

Comment: to add text you don't need margin in bottom but you can use structure where img in top div and bottom div you can add text.but will be easy if you will provide jsfiddle or demo.

Comment: There are many ways to achieve the visual effect you want but it depends on what actual code you have. Please provide us more information, especially CSS of those elements you've mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`overflow: hidden` will help to keep rounded corners when you have an image inside. Check this one - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z4k1j9ch/)

HTML

```
<div class="photocard">
  <a>
    <img src="http://filepic.ru/file/1438412560.jpg" alt="" />
  </a>
  <p>This is Emely</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    background-color: lightgray;
}
.photocard {
    background-color: #fffadc;
    display: block;
    width: 364px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
.photocard p {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Comment: This is awesome! I really appreciate it.

Comment: If you want to set a certain width to `.photocard` div, please add this: `.photocard a, .photocard img{width: inherit;}` now your image always will be the same width as it's container.

Comment: After rendering all photos, I found some shadow was broken. For example, the top shadow of the very top pictures appeared at the very bottom, and the right shadow of the rightmost pictures were missing. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Add an id attribute to the div containing your image. Then add this css to your page:

```
#yourDivId{
margin-top:0px;
margin-left:0px;
margin-right: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check with the below link. I have given class you the image div and gave styling to it.

http://jsfiddle.net/4wz688o1/8/

```
.hello{
margin:0px 0px 100px 0px;
```

}